# why is np.exp(x) not equal to np.exp(1)**x

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, exponential

Why is why is np.exp(x) not equal to np.exp(1)**x?

For example:

```
np.exp(400)
>>>5.221469689764144e+173

np.exp(1)**400
>>>5.221469689764033e+173

np.exp(400)-np.exp(1)**400
>>>1.1093513018771065e+160
```

Comment: I have no experience with Python, but I think it's a rounding issue. The first result is exact, the second one is not, so I assume it's using a less precise value, when multiplied 400 times the rounding issues become bigger. It's like in the second scenario it's doing something like `2.7182818284590451**400` instead of `2.7182818284590452353602874713527**400`. It's strange that the last digit is not the right one, maybe it's a floating point value where the less significant digits may be wrong, unlike a decimal where it's right until the last digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is optimisation of numpy that raise this diff.

Indeed, you have to understand [how is calculated the Euler number](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/e-eulers-number.html#:%7E:text=e%20%28Euler%27s%20Number%29%201%20Calculating.%20There%20are%20many,Interest.%20...%209%20Euler%27s%20Formula%20for%20Complex%20Numbers) in math:

`e = (1/n)**n` with n == inf.

I think numpy stop at a certain order:

You have in the [numpy exp documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html#:%7E:text=The%20irrational%20number%20e%20is%20also%20known%20as,log%20e%20y%2C%20then%20e%20x%20%3D%20y.) here that is not very clear about how the Euler number is calculated.

Because of this order that is not equal to infinity, you have this small difference in the two calculations.

Indeed the value `np.exp(400)` is calculated using this: `(1 + 400/n)**n`

```
>>> (1 + 400/n)**n                                                                                                      
5.221642085428121e+173                                                                                                  
>>> numpy.exp(400)                                                                                                      
5.221469689764144e+173
```

Here you have `n = 1000000000000` wich is very small and raise this difference at 10e-5.

Indeed there is no exact value of the Euler number. Like `Pi`, you can only have an approched value.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a rounding issue. In the first case it's internally using a very precise value of `e`, while in the second you get a less precise value, which when multiplied 400 times the precision issues become more apparent.

The actual result when using the Windows calculator is `5.2214696897641439505887630066496e+173`, so you can see your first outcome is fine, while the second is not.

```
5.2214696897641439505887630066496e+173         // calculator
5.221469689764144e+173                         // exp(400)
5.221469689764033e+173                         // exp(1)**400
```

Starting from your result, it looks it's using a value with 15 digits of precision.

```
2.7182818284590452353602874713527         // e
2.7182818284590450909589085441968         // 400th root of the 2nd result
```